# New reduced user-agent in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, user-agent

After reading [articles](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/user-agent-reduction-oct-2022-updates/) about the changes are coming for user-agent in Google Chrome, I wonder if in the new Google Chrome versions the old user-agent will keep or it will be removed from the request headers.

Do you have any idea about that?

I've used version 113 where it is supposed just the new user-agent is available, but I could check the old one is available too.

So now I'm a bit confused about the migration strategy Google is doing.
[image: Current result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the user-agent will still be present as a request header. the user-agent reduction is removing some information in the string. for example, the subversions of Google Chrome are removed so it only says 113.0.0.0. another example is in mobile user-agents, you wont be able to see the device model in the user-agent(if the device is using chrome)

the information that Google are removing from the UA will be present in user-agent client hints instead https://learnclienthints.com/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! So with this in mind, I suppose the user-agent header will be for more time in the requests.